# How to get submenu to wrap horizontal with no width specified

Tags: html, css, navigation, navbar

I'm trying to keep code to a min so i've created a submenu that will expand and shrink based on the amount of LI that are in the .sub_menu for example if there are only 5 Li or 10 it will wrap around them leaving 5px of margin around all sides even tho it has no width attribute. Yet when I insert it into the main nav it stops working.
 How can I make the submenu div wrap around the LI no matter how many there are?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<style>
/* CSS Document */
html,body{
padding:0px;
margin:0px;
height:100%;
width:100%;
background-color:#f0f0f0;
}
.sub_menu{
position:absolute;
display:inline-block;/*no need for height or width here*/
background-color:#666;
border: 1px solid red;
list-style: none;
margin:0;
padding:0;
}
.sub_menu li{
margin:10px;
display:inline-block;
}
.sub_menu li a{
display:inline-block;
background-color:#F00;
height:100px;
width:100px;
text-decoration:none;
color:#FFF;
}
</style>
<ul class="sub_menu">
<li class="auto body repair"><a href="#">1</a></li>
<li class="rental & loaner"><a href="#">2</a></li>
<li class="hail damage repair"><a href="#">3</a></li>
<li class="towing"><a href="#">4</a></li>
<li class="glass repair"><a href="#">5</a></li>
</ul>
```

and here when sub_menu is inserted into menu it stops working

```css
#navigation{
float:left;
width:70%;
height:100%;
margin:0;
padding:0;
}
#btmenu{
position:relative;
width:100%;
list-style: none;
margin:0;
padding:0;
height:62px;text-align:center;
}
ul#btmenu li{ 
padding:0;
margin:0;
display: inline;
height:62px;
width:200px;

}
#btmenu li > a{ height:62px;
line-height:62px;
margin-left:1%;
margin-right:1%;
text-align:center;
display:inline-block;
text-decoration:none;
font-weight:bold;
font-size:15px;
color:#000;
padding-left:1%;
padding-right:1%;
text-transform:uppercase;
vertical-align: middle;
}
#btmenu > li > a:hover{
background-color:#000;
color:#FFF; 
}
.sub_menu{
display:none;
}
#btmenu .sub_menu li{ 
}
.sub_menu li a{display:block;
background-color:#F00;
height:100px;
width:100px;margin:10px;
text-decoration:none;
color:#FFF;
}
#btmenu > li:hover .sub_menu{
display:block;/*no need for height or width using inline block intill i insert submenu into main menu*/
position:absolute;
background-color:#666;
border: 1px solid red;
list-style: none;
margin:0;
padding:0;
white-space:nowrap;
}
```

```html
<div id="navigation">
<ul id="btmenu">



<li class="top_quote">
  <a href="services">services</a>
  <ul class="sub_menu">
    <li class="auto body repair"><a href="#">1</a></li>
    <li class="rental & loaner"><a href="#">2</a></li>
    <li class="hail damage repair"><a href="#">3</a></li>
    <li class="towing"><a href="#">4</a></li>
    <li class="glass repair"><a href="#">5</a></li>
  </ul></li>

<li class="top_quote"><a href="locations">locations</a>
 <ul class="sub_menu">
    <li class="auto body repair"><a href="#">1</a></li>
    <li class="rental & loaner"><a href="#">2</a></li>
    <li class="hail damage repair"><a href="#">3</a></li>
    <li class="towing"><a href="#">4</a></li>
    <li class="glass repair"><a href="#">5</a></li>
    <li class="glass repair"><a href="#">6</a></li>
    <li class="glass repair"><a href="#">7</a></li>
  </ul></li>
<li class="top_quote"><a href="partners">partners</a>
 <ul class="sub_menu">
    <li class="auto body repair"><a href="#">1</a></li>
    <li class="rental & loaner"><a href="#">2</a></li>
    <li class="hail damage repair"><a href="#">3</a></li>
    <li class="towing"><a href="#">4</a></li>
    <li class="glass repair"><a href="#">5</a></li>
    <li class="glass repair"><a href="#">6</a></li>
    <li class="glass repair"><a href="#">7</a></li>
  </ul></li>
<li class="top_quote"><a href="our work">our work</a></li>
<li class="top_quote"><a href="contact">contact</a></li>

</ul>
</div><!--navigation--
```

Comment: A MINIMAL demo is preferred ....no need to recreate the whole menu.

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem (what you oversaw) is, that your submenu li's inherit from your btmenu li's.

I've created a jsfiddle which fixes your problem (I think, that is what you want): https://jsfiddle.net/jn6xfx4c/

The code needed:

```
ul#btmenu .sub_menu li {
    display: inline-block;
    height: auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

the number of `li` you use takes more width than the container you have itself for the navigation so you need to remove `white-space:nowrap;` from `#btmenu > li:hover .sub_menu` you have in your css, otherwise if you need them to be in the same line so you are going to have horizontal scroll by adding `overflow:auto;` while keeping the `white-space:nowrap;`